# php text doesnt appearing correctly

Tags: php, html, css

Actually I don't know how to search this issue, if it is css or php issue.
I have a div that opens a hidden div. 
When I test the code outside the website it works fine. When I tested inside the website I took this.
see the picture here (http://grab.by/H8TW)

The full construct of the code is:

```
<ol>
<div><div>
<div></div>
<div>
<li>
<div class="lyrics">
<article>
<input type="checkbox" id="read_more" role="button">
<label for="read_more" onclick=""><span>Lyrics</span><span>Hide Lyrics</span></label>
<section></section>    
<section><?php $lyric = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_lyrics', true); echo $lyric; ?>
</section>
</article>​
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
div.lyrics {
position: relative;
top: 10px;
}

article {
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    position: relative;
    *zoom: 1;
}

article:before, article:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}

article:after { clear: both }

article figure {
    float: right;
    width: 32.5%;
}

article section:first-of-type {
    float: left;
    width: 62.5%;
}

article section:last-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;

}

section {
    -webkit-transition: .125s linear;
    -moz-transition: .125s linear;
    -ms-transition: .125s linear;
    -o-transition: .125s linear;
    transition: .125s linear;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

[for="read_more"] {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3rem;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .65rem;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset -1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

[for="read_more"]:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

[for="read_more"] span:last-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ section {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ figure { width: 100% }

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ [for="read_more"] span:first-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ [for="read_more"] span:last-of-type {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Replace `<?php $lyric = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_lyrics', true); echo $lyric; ?>` with some actual text and see if the same happens..If yes you can confirm that this is due to some error in your CSS.

Comment: ok I tried this and and the result is more worst than before! with the actual text Its coming only one line

Comment: may be problem with your cs..could you please post your CSS too..

Comment: @Lal I found a solution but I don't really understand it.
The solution was the way that I paste the text.
If I use the formal text format then the result is what we talking about.
But If I use "enter" for every break I want to have, then the result is the right one. wtf? anyway thank you for your time!

Comment: See this [fillde](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/37asq7fk/).. As you can see your code seems to be working perfectly..

Comment: @lal yes for some reason If use < br > on my text the lines get on its other, but if I use < p > then the text appearing corectly. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of the problem came from the text editor, where I use enter for each break (< br >) I wanted to have! So every text line was a paragraph (< p >).